# Include pdb files into my nuget (nupkg) files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I am using MSBuild to generate my nuget packages.

Is there any command I need to set, to allow it to include my `.pdb` files, for stepping into the source while debugging?

I do not want the source files to be included into the project that is pulling in the nuget package.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Producing**

Simplest way of configuring is to have a `Directory.Build.props` with the common parameters something like this...

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Based on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/ -->
    <!-- Publish the repository URL in the built .nupkg (in the NuSpec <Repository> element) -->
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>

    <!-- Embed source files that are not tracked by the source control manager in the PDB -->
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>

    <!-- Embed symbols containing Source Link in the main file (exe/dll) -->
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)' == 'true'">
    <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
<Project>
```

In each project that produces a package you can then reference the appropriate `SourceLink` assembly for your system.

Explaination as follows:

- *ContinuousIntegrationBuild*: Causes your CI system to produce
  canonical paths to files, should only be set for CI server as
  otherwise you won't be able to find local sources DebugType
- *GeneratedDocumentationFile*: Generates the XML documentation file for inclusion with the dll - you do write docs don't you ;-)
- *Embedded*: Adds the pdb data to the assembly file, simplifies
  distribution at the cost of increasing your dll size

More information at this [MS blog article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/)

**Consuming**

***NET 7***

Copying the symbol files to the execution directory is now incorporated in the [NET 7.0 SDK/VS2022 17.4+](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22362) as an opt-in approach. Add the following fragment to your project file...

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <CopyDebugSymbolFilesFromPackages>true</CopyDebugSymbolFilesFromPackages>
  <CopyDocumentationFilesFromPackages>true</CopyDocumentationFilesFromPackages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will copy all symbols and documentation files into your output directory; if you only want a subset, e.g. *your* files, you will have to implement a filtering mechanism on top of this

***Earlier***

If you are using VS2017 15.4 or later, you can define a MSBuild property in your project file

```
<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
```

This is discussed in [NuGet #4142](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4142#issuecomment-341867400)

However, there is still an issue as the new project system does not copy the pdbs from packages to the bin/publish folder for [.NET Core 3.0+](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458), a good summary is also at [sourcelink/#628](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/628)

As the fix is only supported in the .NET 7 SDK+, you will need a work-around which is to include the following fragment into API and test projects to ensure you have the appropriate pdbs to allow you to step into the remote source code.

```
<!-- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-1063915490 -->
<Target Name="IncludeSymbolFiles" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" Condition="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths) != ''">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.RelativeDir)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename).pdb;                                %(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.RelativeDir)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename).xml" />
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="!Exists('%(FullPath)')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Useful for when I need to do this again, while using Visual Studio 2017. Thanks for your input

Comment: I'm just updating a bunch of my open source projects to VS2017 so I needed it as well :-)

Comment: What element does this go under?  Project, PropertyGroup, or something else? Intellisense isn't picking it up anywhere.

Comment: I've got in my main PropertyGroup - have a look at https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader for a full example

Comment: For the life of me I cannot get this to work.  I'm using VS 2017 15.5.6.  no nuspec file and the following post build event `nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)`

Comment: @kraeg this is for use with the new Pack MSBuild target; I'm not 100% certain how the various tools use each other in this process, but it might be that you're required to use "msbuild /t:Pack" or right click the project and choose "Create NuGet Package" - the old style post-build events should not be required any longer.

Comment: Packaging works this way (my package has the pdb files included now), but how do I use this? When I consume the package, only the DLL file is copied to the target applications bin folder, and if I want to debug into the library, I have to locate the matching pdb under users\username\.nuget\packages... which is not very comfortable.

Comment: @PMF If this is working correctly your nuget package should contain the pdb file as well as the dll.  The other thing to do is to use SourceLink (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink) to ensure the build process references the repository code files. You will also have to disable the "Just my code" option in VS

Comment: @PaulHatcher Yea, the package contains both PDB and DLL, but the PDB is not copied to the application folder of the consuming application automatically. If I really want to debug into the code, I need to manually locate the PDB for the DLL. I think I can't use SourceLink, as these are private repositories (and a private nuget server as well).

Comment: @PMF That's odd, could be version of VS? BTW There are different SourceLink libraries for Git, BitBucket, Azure DevOps plus others; check on NuGet

Comment: @PaulHatcher I'm still using VS2017 (soon to be upgraded, but not towards the end of a project...) I have found a workaround using a targets file for now, but will retest with 2019 later.

Comment: @PMF I think it's only supported from 15.3+, so check you are on at least that

Comment: Yea, it's 15.9.15, so almost the latest version for VS2017.

Comment: I ran into this too, with .NET Core 3. Appears that .NET Core 3 has a bug where PDBs in NuGet packages aren't copied to the bin/publish folder: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3587

Comment: @IGx89 https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-695119194

Comment: Running VS2019 with ASP.NET Core 3.2 does not have this property

Answer (score 42):

While it may not help for debugging, it's definitely useful to include .pdb files so that stack traces have line numbers.

In the nuspec file, include a `<files>` element (child of `<package>`, sibling of `<metadata>`). This is what I have in one of my class libraries:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net452\" />
</files>
```

Make sure the target is the same folder as where your .dll file is put in the package.

Comment: Make sure you add a `file` element for your *\*.dll* files, if you also wish to include them in the NuGet package.

Comment: In my experience, the .dll files are already included - no need to add file elements for them. If you have extra .dll files that are not dependencies, then you might need to add file elements for those.

Comment: It's possible that the *\*.dll* files were excluded because of the old version of Visual Studio I'm using – Visual Studio 2012. But they were excluded nonetheless, until I added a `file` element to explicitly include them.

Comment: @KennyEvitt, i advise you to don't use *.dll in your nuspec. When you have more output than just your own dll, you'll also embed all that other stuf in your package like log4net or entityframework.

Comment: @SvenL Thanks. I don't have ready access to the relevant project anymore but I'm pretty sure I was only explicitly including my project's DLL files and, as I mentioned, I was using an old version of Visual Studio so my experience may not have matched others.

Answer (score 35):

With the .csproj format of .NET Core NuGet creation is much easier, since MSBuild does most of the work.

In order to include your `pdb` files you just have to enter the tag
`<IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>`
in a PropertyGroup in your project's .csproj file.

This will create an additional `.symbols.nupkg` package, which you can release to your [debug] feed.

*Old .NET framework files can be easily mapped to the new csproj with open source libs, like [hvanbakel's repo](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017)*

Comment: This is certainly an easy solution for debugging locally. I'd suggest anyone using the old .csproj format upgrade it to use the new format.

Comment: The best answer ever.

Comment: Where did you get this information? I was unable to find it in the docs. Maybe i looked the wrong place. But a link would be appreciated, so i can read more about it.

Comment: I sincerely don't remember. I think there was an issue in the NuGet dev team Github where this was mentioned. Mostly found how it works via trial & errors.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. It works on Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 9):

This can also be accomplished with the dotnet CLI.

By packaging with

```
dotnet pack --include-symbols --include-source [path-to-project-here]
```

I get full debugging on the packages I generated

Answer (score 4):

The approach that worked for me was adding the PDB as content which had the benefit it will be copied alongside the DLL. (PackageCopyToOutput was required)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(AssemblyName).pdb" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\netstandard2.0\$(AssemblyName).pdb">
       <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

EmbedAllSources - Will include source code in the PDB for easier debugging.

You may also want to consider setting "Optimize" to false for improving debugging experience in release configuration.

Comment: It may work but it makes that folder a part of the project

Comment: How to doing like this for UWP class library?

Answer (score 4):

In 2023, the right way to do this is using SymbolLink.

Include the following NuGet package and it will set all the necessary properties.
https://github.com/dotnet/reproducible-builds

I have used it in my DLL and people are able to debug it.
https://github.com/xavierjohn/FunctionalDDD

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages). Actually you should add *-Symbols* to the end of command to create a symbols package. You shouldn't add pdb files to main nuget package.

Comment: While this is factual and accurate and better, and is indeed the route I took (at first)...  I have gone through so many hours of issues with symbol servers, From the microsoft starter package being deprecated, to the github SymbolServer providing only compressed versions of pdb response files, to visual studio not properly picking the right symbol server in the list of servers, that I'm straight up DONE with symbol servers.  Simply including my .pdb in the nuget right next to the dll, like many other package providers do, works perfectly every time with zero fuss.

Comment: "You shouldn't add pdb files to main nuget package." - Why?

Comment: Currently I don't remember the reason now, but it seems the nuget itself does the necessary things to add corresponding files, explicitly telling nuget to add a pdb file won't generate the desired result. @NeilBarnwell

Answer (score 2):

The newer approach would be to use the following .csproj properties:

```
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
<EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
```

EmbedAllSources - Will include source code in the PDB for easier debugging.

Setting DebugType to embedded will cause the PDB to be embedded in the .DLL.

So using the two options together the source code will be embedded in the DLL.