# Publish .snupkg to Azure DevOps artifacts nuget feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211644/publish-snupkg-symbol-package-to-private-feed-in-vsts) asks one of the questions I am asking - Can I publish a .snupkg to a Azure DevOps feed?  Since the post is over two years old I would like to know if the functionality has since been implemented.

If the answer to the above is yes, I would like to know how to do it via an Azure build pipeline.  The push task for my current pipeline is here:

```
task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'LeaderAnalyticsFeed'
    publishVstsFeed: 'LeaderAnalyticsFeed'
    includeSymbols: true
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.snupkg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still cannot do this now, See the ticket you shared and [Alternative PDB distribution](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#alternative-pdb-distribution):

> `.snupkg` symbol packages have some limitations:
>
> - Not supported by Azure DevOps Artifacts service.

In addition, I found a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-snupkg-support-to-azure-devops-artifacts/657354) and the state is `Under Review`, you could follow the ticket to get the latest news. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.