# include file for each target framework in nuget

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, msbuild-itemgroup

I have a project (SDK style) with several target frameworks:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I build it, a `pdb` file is generated for each target framework. I want to include these `pdb` files in the nuget next to their corresponding `dll` (so, in `\lib\targetFramework\`).

I am able to do it for one specific framework:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\$(Configuration)\net48\*.pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net48" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**How can I specify this for all `TargetFrameworks` without hard-coding?**

---

I can do it generically if I have the collection of all `TargetFrameworks` transformed in a certain way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- hard-coded collection -->
  <PDBFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\net48\$(AssemblyName).pdb">
    <NugetFramework>net48</NugetFramework>
  </PDBFile>
  <PDBFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp3.1\$(AssemblyName).pdb">
    <NugetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</NugetFramework>
  </PDBFile>
  <PDBFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\net5.0-windows\$(AssemblyName).pdb">
    <NugetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</NugetFramework>
  </PDBFile>
  <PDBFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\net6.0-windows\$(AssemblyName).pdb">
    <NugetFramework>net6.0-windows7.0</NugetFramework>
  </PDBFile>

  <!-- generic usage of the collection -->
  <Content Include="@(PDBFile)" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\%(NugetFramework)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I still don't know how to define the `PDBFile` collection in a less hard-coded way...

Comment: Are you specifically asking about including the pdb or arbitrary files in general? For PDBs there already is a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713693/include-pdb-files-into-my-nuget-nupkg-files

Comment: @MartinUllrich Both. I'll try the approach you linked, but I might need to copy arbitrary files at some point. One goal of my question is to learn more about the MSbuild language.